# Building and sending very large CSV data-set over C# WCF REST Web Service as MemoryStream

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, csv, memorystream

This topic is related to the question here:

[How to send a CSV file using C# WCF RESTful (i.e. Web) Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197901/how-to-send-a-csv-file-using-c-sharp-wcf-restful-i-e-web-service)

I was able to send a very small data set by utilizing the method discussed at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web.aspx, which explains how to utilize a "RAW" programming model to send the response -- I'm using the MemoryStream class.

```
public Stream ReturnCSVSample()
{
    string csv = "Hello, World\nGoodBye, For, Now\n";
    byte[] csvBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv);

    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/csv";

    return new MemoryStream(csvBytes);
}
```

This works fine.  However, in reality, I'm retrieving about 144,000 records from a SQL database table, two columns wide, and using string concatenation to format it into CSV.  Then, I take this string,encode it as a bytes array and return it as a MemoryStream object.  I let the service run for over 20 minutes and it still does not finish!  I've determined the bottleneck is the string concatenation.  Why?  Because I performed the operation of retrieving these 144,000 records and storing it to a class I created and it took a few minutes, at most, to complete.

Either a string that large is inefficient or there is a better method to perform string concatenation for the amount of records I specified.

How can I send a CSV stream over a web service with such as a large data set?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I also saw your other WCF rest service CSV question and upvoted. Why did you not go with the `IDispatchMessageFormatter` approach? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A `StreamWriter()` would do a better job than string concatenation:

```
public Stream LoadStreamSample(Stream ms)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8)){
        // Call SQL and iterate over rows from SqlDataReader here...
        while (dr.Read()){
            // replace following with csv of one record
            string csv = "Hello, World\nGoodBye, For, Now\n";
            sw.WriteLine(csv)
        }
    }
    return ms;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was looking up the difference between String and StringBuilder and it seems I should've been using StringBuilder for this task.  What is the performance difference between StreamWriter and StringBuilder?

Comment: @user717236 `StreamWriter` and `StringBuilder` aren't directly comparable. However,   `StringWriter`, which inherits `StreamWriter`, uses a `StringBuilder` internally, so there is very little difference. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602279/stringwriter-or-stringbuilder